# If chromatic polynomials for two graphs agree, can I always find an edge such that the two deletion-contraction minors have same chromatic polynomial?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, counterexamples

Suppose I have non-isomorphic graphs $G$ and $H$ (which have at least one edge), but such that their chromatic polynomials are the same. Can I then always find an edge $e$ in $G$ and $f$ in $H$ such that the chromatic polynomials for the deletions $G\setminus e$ and $H \setminus f$ coincide as well?

I suspect not, but I have not managed to construct a counterexample.

Comment: The keyword "chromatically equivalent" may help you find literature on this topic.